# Execute action without redirecting(Add to wishlist)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I have some product cards that I'm displaying with a foreach loop. When I click a link, I want to add that product to my wishlist (Session["wishList"]). That calls a function and redirects me to /product/wishlist/01, where 01 is the product id.

My temporary fix is `return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>window.history.back();</script>");` but no reloading would be better.

My code:

```
<code>
 <a href="@Url.Action("AddToWishList", "Product", new {id = item.Id})"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
</code>
```

Controller:

```
<code>
public ActionResult AddToWishList(int id)
        {
            if (Session["email"] != null && Session["role"] != null && (WebApplication1.Models.RoleType)Session["role"] == Models.RoleType.User)
            {
                var wishList = (List<int>)Session["wishList"];
                if (wishList.Contains(id))
                {
                    wishList.Remove(id);
                }
                else
                {
                    wishList.Add(id);
                }
                Session["wishList"] = wishList;
            }
            return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>window.history.back();</script>");
        }</code>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Ajax` for this purpose?

Comment: @RahulSharma I'll have to take a look at that. Didn't try before.

Comment: Okay. I will try to give an example to you. I will post an answer on how you can use `Ajax` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ajax` in your case which is used to update a portion of the page without reloading the entire page. In your case, you can do something like:

Define a function which will take a the `id` of the selected element:

```
<code>
 <a href="#" onClick='addToWishList('@item.Id')'><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
</code>
```

Then you need to define a function which will take this `id` and send it to your `Controller` via `Ajax`:

```
<script>

function addToWishList(id)
{
    var json = {
        id : id
    }; 
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("AddToWishList", "Product")",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.status=="true")
          {
            alert(data.msg);
            var urlToRedirect= '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
            window.location.href = urlToRedirect; //Redirect here
          }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('Some error');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And then finally in your `Controller`, you can process this `id` and then return back a result:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToWishList(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    //Get your variables here from AJAX call
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(jsondata["id"]);
    if (Session["email"] != null && Session["role"] != null && (WebApplication1.Models.RoleType)Session["role"] == Models.RoleType.User)
    {
        var wishList = (List<int>)Session["wishList"];
        if (wishList.Contains(id))
        {
            wishList.Remove(id);
        }
        else
        {
            wishList.Add(id);
        }
        Session["wishList"] = wishList;
    }
    
    return Json(new {status="true", msg= "Successfully processed"});
}
```

You can tailor the methods as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked! Seems like I have a lot more to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Implementing callbacks in your page could work:

- **ASP.Net :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms366518(v=vs.100)
- **ASP.Net MVC :** https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetMvc/9052/common-features/callback-based-functionality